# In Frosty the Snowman (1969), did Frosty return the next day after he left for the North Pole?

Tags: frosty-the-snowman

In the movie, Santa told Hinkle just maybe you will get a present in your stocking **tomorrow** morning. This means it was still the night of December 24th when Frosty left with Santa to the North Pole. When Frosty left on the sleigh, he said he will be back on Christmas Day, which would be the very next day.

Answer (score 1):

> When Frosty left on the sleigh, he said he will be back on Christmas Day, which would be the very next day.

### It's not stated but probably not.

It seems unlikely that Frosty would join Santa as part of the delivery of Christmas gifts.

All we are told is that Frosty returned every year **when the "Christmas Snow" returned.**